# Inner join in play framework ebean

Tags: java, playframework, inner-join, ebean

I have a query which i want to write in my Product model

```
select * from shop inner join product on product.shops_id=shop.id where product.name=keyword
```

**Shop.java**

```
public class Shop extends Model {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="shop_gen", sequenceName="shop_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="shop_gen")
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public String addressLine1;

    public String addressLine2;

    public String addressLine3;

    @Required
    public String city;

    @Required
    public String town;

    @Required
    public String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shops",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();


    @Required
    @OneToOne
    public String category;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "shop_pic")
    public  byte[] shop_pic;


    @ManyToOne
    @Required
    public User owner;

}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product extends Model {
   @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="product_gen", sequenceName="product_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="product_gen")
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long id;
    @Required
    public String name;
    @Required
    public Float price;
    @OneToOne
    @Required
    public String category;
    @ManyToOne
    public Shop shops;
}
```

My main aim is to find list of shops which has a particular product.

where keyword change everytime.
i have referred to similar question  but dint understand any of them.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

With proper relations in your models it would be:

```
Shop.find.where().like("product.name", keyword).findList();
```

Anyway we don't know nothing about your models.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution to your problem:

At first add finder to Product class

```
public static Finder<Long,Product> find = new Finder<Long,Product>(
    Long.class, Product.class
);
```

Change attribute `shops` to `shop` in Product class. It is inappropriate to give plural name when there is single object.

Then to retrieve list of shops containing a product of a given name add code similar to this:

```
List<Product> productList = Product.find.where().like("name", keyword).findList();
List<Shop> shopList = new ArrayList<Shop>();
for(Product product:productList)
    shopList.add(product.shop);
```